# Integral operator with Bessel kernel

Tags: operator-theory, bessel-functions

For $x,y\ge 0$, let
$$
k(x,y)= \frac {J_1(2\sqrt{xy})}{\sqrt{xy}},
$$
where $J_1$ is the the Bessel function of the first kind
$$
J_{1}(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k} \frac{\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^{2 k+1}}{k !(k+1) !}.
$$
Does this kernel give a bounded linear operator on $L^2(0,+\infty)$:
$$
 Af(x) =\int_{0}^\infty k(x,y) f(y) dy.
$$
Note that the kernel $k(x,y)$ is not square-integrable since
$$
\int_0^\infty \left( \frac {J_1(2\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}}\right)^2 dx= 1.
$$

Cross post [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/363550/integral-operator-with-bessel-kernel)